# PHP - Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, redhat

I am encountering the following errors when I try to run my webpage, which has a php script embedded to call a mysql database:

---

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/dbase.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/dbase.so: undefined symbol: core_globals in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so: undefined symbol: executor_globals in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: executor_globals in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo.so: undefined symbol: executor_globals in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: executor_globals in Unknown on line 0
[notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) configured -- resuming normal operations
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/index.php on line 11
```

---

I have checked my php.ini file and have verified the `extension_dir` directive references the correct directory i.e. `/usr/lib64/php/modules/`

Is anyone able to shed some light on why these errors are occurring?

Comment: That is a config issue and not a programming question.

Comment: Have you custom-compiled php? I believe this is caused by compiling with --enable-versioning, which is incompatible with loadable modules: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=24853

Comment: I think you're have a bad installation, maybe different versions of php lib and php itself . You must provide more Information like version,  webserver, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should open your php.ini file located in php folder, and uncomment this line of code:

```
;extension=php_mysql.dll
```

then it will look like this:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

Comment: Is php_mysql.dll only applicable to a windows installation?

Comment: @user3717786 Yes '.dll' are windows only dynamic link libraries, on Linux it'll be php_mysql.so

Comment: [I need help!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68645549/1883256) I can't load sqlsrv extensions :(