# Laravel Homestead PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library sqlsrv.so and pdo_sqlsrv.so

Tags: sql-server, symfony4, homestead, php-extension, sqlsrv

I have got to work on a Symfony v4.2, that connects to an external MS SQL Server database. The error I get is:

> Attempted to call function "sqlsrv_configure" from the global
> namespace.

I know there're already posts about it, but none focused on Laravel Homestead, that runs on Ubuntu 20.04.2.

I am running Homestead v12.3.1, Settler v11.3.0.

So far, I have understood that I should install both the `sqlsrv` and `pdo_sqlsrv` extensions.

I have just done that. In this case, given the fact that in Laravel Homestead there are several versions of PHP that you can switch:

`$ sudo update-alternatives --config php`:

```
There are 7 choices for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

  Selection    Path             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php5.6   56        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/php7.1   71        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/php7.3   73        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/php7.4   74        manual mode
  7            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        manual mode
```

As you can see, I am currently using the 7.0 ... it actually can be any.

What I did to install the extensions was to execute the following commands:

`$ sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev` [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55037401/1883256)

And the following, according to [this other reference](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/step/2.html):

`$ sudo pecl install sqlsrv`

`$ sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv`

And the output was:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20200930/sqlsrv.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/sqlsrv-5.9.0
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=sqlsrv.so" to php.ini


Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/pdo_sqlsrv-5.9.0
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" to php.ini
```

Indeed

`$ ls -lah /usr/lib/php/20200930/`

Those `sqlsrv.ini` and `pdo_sqlsrv.ini` do exist.

But then, when I searched for those recently installed extensions

`$ php -m | grep sqlsrv`

`$ php -m | grep pdo_sqlsrv`

the result was empty.

Then I restarted the php-fpm service like so:

`$ sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm`

`$ php -m`

But I got these warnings:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol: zval_ptr_dtor in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20200930/sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20200930/sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol: zval_ptr_dtor in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol: zval_ptr_dtor in Unknown on line 0
```

Then I changed directory to

`$ cd /etc/php/7.0/mods-available`

and `$ ls -lah`

and edited both the

**sqlsrv.ini**

```
; priority=20
extension=/usr/lib/php/20200930/sqlsrv.so
```

**pdo_sqlsrv.ini**

```
; priority=30
extension=/usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

files.

And I get the same error.

Moreover, even if I change the files to:

**sqlsrv.ini**

```
; priority=20
extension=sqlsrv.so
```

**pdo_sqlsrv.ini**

```
; priority=30
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

Now I get an slightly different error in the directory:

`$ php -m`

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

It looks like it simply can't load the libraries :(

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62259296/1883256)

`$ find / -name 'sqlsrv' 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied'`

returns ( [command reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42842/274791) ):

```
/usr/share/php/docs/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.1/cli/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.1/cgi/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.1/fpm/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.1/phpdbg/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.4/cli/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.4/cgi/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.4/fpm/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.4/phpdbg/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.3/cli/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.3/cgi/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.3/fpm/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.3/phpdbg/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.0/cli/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.0/cgi/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.0/fpm/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.0/phpdbg/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/5.6/cli/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/5.6/cgi/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/5.6/fpm/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/5.6/phpdbg/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.2/cli/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.2/cgi/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.2/fpm/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/7.2/phpdbg/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/8.0/cli/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/8.0/cgi/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/8.0/fpm/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
/var/lib/php/modules/8.0/phpdbg/enabled_by_admin/sqlsrv
```

`$ find / -name 'sqlsrv.so' 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied'`

```
/usr/lib/php/20200930/sqlsrv.so
```

`$ find / -name 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied'`

```
/usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

Another try I did was according to [yet this another answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1070246/470071), where I executed:

`$ pear config-set php_ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini`

And I got:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol: zval_ptr_dtor in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20200930/sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20200930/sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol: zval_ptr_dtor in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol: zval_ptr_dtor in Unknown on line 0
config-set succeeded
```

But I still get the same warnings.

[Here's a small explanation](https://beberlei.de/2017/03/29/why_does_the_php_extension_fail_to_load_with_zval_ptr_dtor_wrapper_error.html), and [there](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/772) but I don't get it :(

What else do I have to do to make PHP load those both `sqlsrv.so` and `pdo_slqsrv.so` extensions here on Laravel Homestead?

Are there any other alternatives where I can use a Symfony 4.2 app with the `sqlsrv` extension enabled? Maybe a virtual machine? Any ideas? Can anyone shed some good light to have this Symfony 4.2 app up and running and being able to connect with a 2017 MS SQL Server?